# Azure App Service deployment failure, could not locate assembly just installed

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have a NET 4.6 Web App that uses ASP.NET Core 1.1 on Azure. This Web App has a dependency on a NET 4.6 Class Library which has a dependency on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (Version=1.1.1.0).

When I deploy it from Git for the first time I get messages of packages installing, like this one:

> Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.1.0.

In fact I get three different lines that install Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives versions: 1.1.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.0.

But in the same deployment I get over 35 errors on the Class Library project, that say that it could not locate an assembly that it just installed. One of them is Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives:

> D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0-preview1-005977\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\ClassLibraryNet462\ClassLibraryNet462.csproj]

I see that it is trying to use NET Core 2.0.0-preview1-005977, but I don't know why. I guess that may be part of the problem.

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve it?